# How to implement SCSS in Angular2 Seed Project?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

How to implement SCSS in Angular2 Seed Project.? is there any better tutorial or reference sites to see this?

I tried implementing the same in this link 
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components

but I am getting this error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/subscription/subscription.component.scss
Module parse failed: C:\indiaAbroad\iaApp\src\app\components\subscription\subscription.component.scss Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .subscription {
|
| }
 @ ./src/app/components/subscription/subscription.component.ts 18:21-61
 @ ./src/app/config/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi main                                            Hash: e76bd7a5a02aa33e1272
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/components/subscription/subscription.component.scss
Module parse failed: C:\indiaAbroad\iaApp\src\app\components\subscription\subscription.component.scss Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .subscription {
|
| }
 @ ./src/app/components/subscription/subscription.component.ts 18:21-61
 @ ./src/app/config/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct.

Once installed this package restart the npm server. It will work!!!

Answer (score 2):

> `npm install node-sass sass-loader raw-loader --save-dev`
>
> In webpack.common.js, search for "rules:"
>
> ```
> {
>     test: /\.scss$/,
>     exclude: /node_modules/,
>     loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
> }
> ```
>
> [source](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular ClI. It has support for sass styles

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

```
ng new project --style scss
```

Comment: Is Angular CLI suitable to use in production environments

Comment: there's a command to package your app for production when it's ready. `ng build --environment prod`. I have used it in multiple projects and I must say it's very handy and can save you a lot of time.